# AOS library and Angular, scroll animation not triggered on click on a navbar link for same page section navigation

Tags: angular, typescript, aos.js

As the question implies, the scrolling animation works as intended, but when I click on a link from the navigation bar it does take me to the contact section on the same page (for example) but it does not detect a mouse scroll thus not triggering the animations on that section.

Any help or idea would be appreciated!

EDIT:
Using an Click event to scroll to the desired section from the navbar

```
goTo(location: string): void {
   window.location.hash = location;

   //Tried using this, but it does trigger the animation on scroll up, not on scroll down
   AOS.refresh();
}
```

Comment: Can you provide a little bit of code what you are asking for ?

Comment: @nideba, please check the edit